# weak_ptr, make_shared and memory deallocation

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, weak-ptr, make-shared

A control block of a `shared_ptr` is kept alive while there is at least one `weak_ptr` present. If the shared pointer was created with `make_shared` that implies that the whole memory of the object is kept allocated. (The object itself is properly destructed, but since the control block and the memory for the object were allocated in one chunk, as `make_shared` does, they can only be deallocated together.)

Is my understanding correct?

It seems that this behaviour represents a problem, for example in the famous ["cache example"](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/My-Favorite-Cpp-10-Liner). The memory for the objects will be kept allocated forever.

It it a problem in any practical situations? Shall the `shared_ptr` be created using a constructor in such a situation (large object and intent to use `weak_ptr`s)?

Comment: Yes, but remember many "large" objects will allocate their own memory dynamically, e.g an object composed of a `std::vector`, so that dynamically allocated memory _will_ be deallocated when the object is destroyed. You only need to worry if the size of the object itself is large, e.g a large `std::array`.

Comment: If you are worried about exception safety you could use `make_unique` instead and then construct a `shared_ptr` from your `unique_ptr`: e.g `std::shared_ptr<BigObject> ptr = std::make_unique<BigObject>();`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is my understanding correct?

Yes. If your `weak_ptr`s significantly outlive the (large) object and you are tight on memory, it may be beneficial to avoid `make_shared`.

However, "large" here is measured by `sizeof`, and many conceptually "large" objects (for example, most standard containers, except `std::array`) are quite small by that metric, because they allocate additional memory to store their contents, which will be freed as soon as the object is destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this in VS2013 and you're completely correct. The destructor is called when the last shared_ptr is destroyed, so any other objects or memory associated with the object will be destroyed, but if the shared_ptr is created with make_shared the memory is never destroyed until the last weak_ptr is.

I think it's always good to clean up or reset your weak_ptrs if lock() fails because even without make_shared it's still using some memory.

Comment: "_it's always good to clean up or reset (...)_" yes but there is nothing prevented the implementation from doing it automatically